# How does one run a dotnet WebAPIApplication in Docker on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows-10, .net-core

I apologize for any arrogance, but I can't figure out how to run a WebAPIApp on Windows 10 for the life of me. My Docker for Windows is using Windows Containers, as Linux Containers causes Docker to crash upon starting. I have tried using my own app and got the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container [id] encountered an error during CreateContainer: lost communication with compute service
```

I tried running the two following as well, with the same result.

```
docker run microsoft/dotnet-samples:dotnetapp-nanoserver

docker run microsoft/dotnet-samples
```

If you know the solution or need extra information please let me know. I am running Windows 10 and have also tried following [this](https://raygun.com/blog/net-core-docker-container/) guide, which has noted problems of its' own.

**EDIT:**

The issue seems to be with [Sohpos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us.aspx), will update again when more info is present

Comment: It is worth noting that running anything else in Docker works, and I only get this error whenever my daemon encounters a dotnet command.

Comment: according to [microsoft/dotnet-samples](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-samples/~/dockerfile/), it's based on [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/~/dockerfile/), which is a linux image. I don't think you can run that on Windows container.